# How to do lossless exporting?

Tags: google-docs, export, import

I have several documents created using Google Docs. They are not plain text documents, but documents with images, tables, etc, etc.

How can I export this Google Document to my computer, such that I can import them back into Google Docs at a future date?

The only export options I see are .docx, .odt, .rtf, .pdf, .txt, and .html:

[image]

However these options are lossy. My documents are not *byte-for-byte-equal* after exporting and re-importing.

How can I losslessly export my Google Documents?

Comment: What does "email as attachment" do?

Comment: @barrycarter, It asks which format I want to convert to before emailing:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/k2MvN.png . All available formats are lossy. "Publish to the web" also only has lossy options.

Comment: What does "paste the item..." do?

Comment: @barrycarter, It tries to paste the document directly into the email. Much data is lost though.

Answer (score 0):

You can export Google Docs in their native format by appending `export?format=kix` to a Google Docs file link. However, even with the API, there's no way to re-import this file into docs at this time.

Comment: Interesting but what can be done with the "native format" out of Google Docs?

Comment: @Rubén Nothing that I'm aware of. It's plain text file the begins with the content and ends with formatting included in a format I'm not familiar with.